# Why my CPU is running hot and throttling?

Tags: cpu, fan, cooling, temperature, throttling

Anytime I try to play games my CPU is getting too hot. I used CoreTemp and HWiNFO64 to measure the temp of the CPU and GPUs and they showed CPU's temperature going to 95+ ºC.

**My system specs are:**
Alienware m17x R2
Intel Core i7-920XM
AMD Mobility Radeon HD 5870 2x
8 GB RAM
1 TB HD
Microsoft Windows 10 Professional
Fan AVC BATA1015R5H

**I already tried:**

  Re-paste the CPU with different thermal paste

  Clean the dust that could be blocking the air stream

  Oiled the cooler fan

  Changed the CPU

  Changed the heatsink

The max RPM of the fan recorded by the programs is 3.800; I don't know if it is the real max because I didn't find the fan manual on the Internet. Does anyone has a clue on how to fix this problem?

Comment: This sounds like a installation problem. Have you cleaned up the old paste before applying the new paste? How much you used? Are you sure the heat sink is applied tightly to the CPU surface? If you think everything is done right, then probably your fan is worn out and you need a new one. What I did in the past is to find a fan of the same size but higher current rating and more blades (from stock 11-blade 0.13A to 17-blade 0.35A).

Comment: I'd replace the fan which you oiled unless you're sure your fan needs to be oiled and you used the right oil. Modern fans don't work like that and the oil has a certain potential to slow down the fan, which is probably not exactly what you intended.

Comment: Are you over clocked? I ask because so many people do this. And it's worth the time and effort to take your whole box to a place like Fry's or a PC shop and have them inspect it and see if you can get a better fan perhaps or add a fan. Those hardware tech guys know their stuff. It's not really worth discussing theoretically at this point I think.

Comment: I re-pasted at least 5 times to be sure that wasn't installation problem. I used less than a drop of thermal paste in the center of the processor.
I suspected olied would not help... but I tryed anyaway as last resource...
I forgot to say I'm not over clocked.....
I just ordered a new fan, I will try a new one with Artic Silver thermal paste

Answer (score 0):

Time to time it is recommendable to change the CPU thermal Paste... I really advice this since I change mine every year, to improve cpu temps. If you haven't done it, you should do it ASAP, by the way it seems your PC is about 7-6 years old, most probably the original cheap intel paste is already dry and cracked and  its not doing its job at all...

[image: paste]

**I recommend you apply Arctic silver 5** 
http://www.arcticsilver.com/as5.htm

Further reading:

1. http://www.techspot.com/community/topics/how-often-should-i-replace-my-thermal-paste.178411/
2. https://linustechtips.com/main/topic/133327-how-often-do-you-change-your-cpu-thermal-paste/

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I already did it using exactly the thermal paste you sugestioned. I tried using differents application methods. No sucess.